# Hardness of $SIS$ and its reduction to an NP-complete problem

Tags: lattice-crypto, sis

Short Integer Solution ($ SIS_\gamma^{(q,n,m,\beta)}$): Given a matrix $A\in Z_{q}^{n×m}$, find $x \in Z^m $, such that $Ax=0\mod q$ and $||x|| \le \beta$

Is $SIS\in NP$ ?

If $SIS \in NP$, then it should be reduced to any NP-complete problem.

Is there any reduction from $SIS$ to a Hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: Yes: the witness is such an x; it can be efficiently checked that it satisfies the conditions. The Cook-Levin theorem gives a reduction from any NP problem to SAT, which we know how to reduce to Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert Could you maybe convert your comment to an answer?