# Cryptography based on #P-complete problems

Tags: encryption, complexity, computational-complexity-theory

Are there any examples of a cryptographic scheme based on (an average-case form of) a #P-complete problem?

Comment: We don't know how to base cryptography (e.g., one-way functions) even on NP-completeness (and there are known barriers to this) let alone #P completeness.

Comment: Also, #P has a worst-case to average case reduction (so one may as well assume average-case hardness).

Answer (score 2):

We don't know how to base cryptography even on $\mathbf{NP}$-completeness let alone $\#\mathbf{P}$-completeness. Moreover, there are known barriers to basing cryptography on $\mathbf{NP}$-completeness: [AGGM,BT], and also [Chapter 7, B].

That said, it one is willing to make additional assumptions then $\#\mathbf{P}$-hardness can be useful: e.g., in [CHK+], it is shown that in the [random-oracle model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle), hardness of $\#SAT$ (which is complete for $\#\mathbf{P}$) can yield hard distributions of Nash, the problem of computing [Nash equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium) (of, say, two-player games).

[AGGM]: Akavia, Goldreich, Goldwasser and Moshkovitz, *[On Basing One-Way Functions on NP-Hardness](https://people.csail.mit.edu/akavia/2006-stocAGGM.pdf)*, STOC 2006

[B]: Brzuszka, *[On the Foundations of Key Exchange](https://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/3414/)*, PhD Thesis, 2013

[BT]: Bogdanov and Trevisan, *[On Worst-Case to Average-Case Reductions for NP Problems](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/eccc-reports/2005/TR05-015/index.html)*, FOCS 2003

[CHK+]: Choudhuri et al, *[Finding a Nash Equilibrium Is No Easier Than Breaking Fiat-Shamir](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2019/074/)*, STOC 2019

Comment: Thanks - helpful answer! Particularly the second paragraph - I had in mind something like a #P-complete equivalent of e.g. this question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55724/hardness-of-sis-and-its-reduction-to-an-np-complete-problem. The hardness of Nash is exactly the kind of example I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: The following answer does not cover the original question. It is the result of confusing [p-complete](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete) with [#p-complete](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete).**

The first ever public key cryptographic algorithm was based on a p-complete problem. It is today known as [Merkle Puzzle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%27s_Puzzles). Roughly speaking, the complexity of key exchange for the receiving and sending sides is $\mathcal{O}(n)$ while a  successful attack complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

Although in modern cryptography, it is not considered secure anymore, Merkle's idea changed everything in cryptography.

Comment: Interesting! But I don't think that that example is in #P.

Comment: This was definitely my mistake. Confusing p-complete and #p-complete.